# How do i take the backup of my Drupal 6 database and import it in to Drupal 7.12?

Tags: drupal

I'm literally a week in to Drupal, so a newbie to it. Basically I've made a backup of a Drupal 6 database, made a clean install of Drupal 7.12 and now need to import everything in to my new database

I tried using the feeds module yesterday and imported the users table from a csv file, that worked, but it didnt work for the nodes import, it said  it imported 1 node and updated 500+,

I can see there's different fields in the tables in drupal 7 so I'm wondering if there's a way to import everything or will i have to do it manually?

Thanks

---

Update
Just to update you guys, managed to get a backup of the drupal 6 site and went over the installation procedure again, followed the upgrade document down to the T and it's imported everything fine, i guess i didn't disable modules last time or rushed in to it too quickly as the update to drupal 6.24 from 6.13 went smooth..

Oh well, it's been a learning curve that's for sure..thank for taking the time to answer guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database structure has changed a lot between 6 and 7, so there's no direct way to import an old base to the new one.

I think you should give Feeds another try, as the message you mention shows you were close to have something working. There is an option in Feeds which lets you forbid it from updating nodes, but forces it to create new ones. Perhaps it's worth a go.

Also, you don't detail the procedure you used, but you D6 content should be carefully exported before trying the import in D7. If your content types are not too complex, you could probably fetch the content directly from the old sites URLS using Feeds HTML parser.

Hope to give you hints to put you on the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know should be found [here](http://drupal.org/node/548922) or elsewhere on drupal.org

Comment: When I upgraded the first time it told me I needed to empty the database as Drupal was already installed, so that's what I did, but i can't figure a way to import everything i need from my backup. I've read the info from the link but it doesn't state how to import everything, any ideas? i'm guessing i've done it all wrong

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to clear the database.  Did you disable all modules (not un-install), then run the updates?  Sounds like maybe you replaced the config file and the clear file was reporting the database was structured.  Make sure you're running the old config file and only need to update (not reinstall).